# The retrofit API call is initiated after i try to display the results

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using the MVVM architecture, i have my model class "Category" and my ViewModel class and the MainActivity and Adapter for Recyclerview ,
All is works fine if i set the adapter inside the activity (inside onResponse methode of the Retrofit Call), but if i do it this way im not respecting the separation of the MVVM architecture,
here is the methode that use to excute the call :

```
 public List<Category> getcategories() {

    RestInterface restInterface = rest.getInterfaceService();
    Call<List<Category>> productService = restInterface.getCategories();
    productService.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {
            if (response.body() == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "responce Call response is null ");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "repo : "+response.body().toString());
                categories = (ArrayList<Category>) response.body();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Call Fail  : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
    Log.e(TAG, "repo 2: "+categories.toString());
    return categories;
}
```

here is the logcat results :

07-11 20:18:34.325 24369-24369/com.instadom E/DataRepository: repo 2: []

07-11 20:18:35.399 24369-24369/com.instadom E/DataRepository: repo : [exemple.com.models.Category@1df175e, exemple.com.models.Category@5cfc73f, exemple.com.models.Category@1e7380c, exemple.com.models.Category@7ceb555, exemple.com.models.Category@3014b6a, exemple.com.models.Category@a83985b, exemple.com.models.Category@3d5c8f8, exemple.com.models.Category@d1251d1]

what i can't understand is why i don't get any result in the "Log.e(TAG, "repo 2: "+categories.toString());"   even tho "categories" is a class object

I would apreciate any help,
thanks in advance,

---

Here is the code :

> public List getcategories(final Callback>
>   callback) {
>           RestInterface restInterface = rest.getInterfaceService();
>           Call> productService = restInterface.getCategories();
>           productService.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback>() {
>               @Override
>               public void onResponse(Call> call, Response> response) {
>                   if (response.body() == null){
>                       Log.e(TAG, "responce Call response is null ");
>                   }else{
>                       Log.e(TAG, "repo : "+response.body().toString());
>                       categories = (ArrayList) response.body();
>                       callback.onSuccess(categories);
>                   }
>               }
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {
>             Log.e(TAG, "Call Fail  : " + t.getMessage());
>             callback.onFailure(t.getMessage());
>         }
>     });
>     Log.e(TAG, "result : "+categories.toString());
>     return categories;
> }
> public interface Callback<T> {
>     void onSuccess(ArrayList<Category> data);
>     void onFailure(String reason);
> }
> ```

here is the error :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void instadom.com.repositories.DataRepository$Callback.onSuccess(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Comment: Isn't this an asyc call and the latter Log is being called before the onResponse? I think you can fix this working with listeners

Comment: You should use LiveData or RxJava to get notified in Activity when data received from web API

Answer (score 2):

That is because `productService.enqueue` is an asynchronous call, The statement `Log.e(TAG, "repo 2: "+categories.toString());` will be executed right after the call is is enqued and the `onResponse` or `onFailure` will be executed after a network call. pass in a callback to the `getCategories()` to get the category list like this

```
public interface Callback<List<Categories>> callback{
   void onSuccess(List<Categories> data);
   void onFailure(String reason);
}
```

or you can use a generic callback interface to use in all your network requests like this

```
public interface Callback<T> callback{
   void onSuccess(List<T> data);
   void onFailure(String reason);
}
```

then implement the callback functionality

```
public List<Category> getcategories(Callback<List<Category>> callback) {

    RestInterface restInterface = rest.getInterfaceService();
    Call<List<Category>> productService = restInterface.getCategories();
    productService.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {
            if (response.body() == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "responce Call response is null ");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "repo : "+response.body().toString());
                categories = (ArrayList<Category>) response.body();
                callback.onSuccess(categories);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Call Fail  : " + t.getMessage());
            callback.onError(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but this doesn"t seem to wrok,